# sec:authorize doesn't work on spring security

Tags: html, spring-boot, gradle, spring-security, thymeleaf

sec:authorize doesn't work...
It's my index.html code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ko"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/extras/spring-security">
<!--xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5"> -->
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;" charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>title</title>
</head>
<body>
<div sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()">
    <a href="/logout">Logout</a>
</div>
<div sec:authorize="!isAuthenticated()">
    <a href="/user/login">Login</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried to run with springsecurity5 namespace, but it failed too.
I don't know why this doesn't work.

index.html output
[image]

It's my build.gradle config only about dependencies.

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.thymeleaf.extras:thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5'
    implementation 'org.modelmapper:modelmapper:2.3.0'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    runtimeOnly 'mysql:mysql-connector-java'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}
```

It's my spring security config code.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/user/login", "/user/signIn", "/", "/incomeMap").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/user/login")
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/user/login")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/login");
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("admin").password("{noop}admin").roles("ADMIN")
                .and()
                .withUser("user").password("{noop}user").roles("USER");
    }
}
```

and `<div sec:authorize>` have not wrought with these config and code.

Comment: Is the index.html in the "src/main/resources/templates" folder?

Comment: Yes, that was why it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use thymeleaf only like:

```html
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:sec="https://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5">
...
<body>
        ...
        <a th:if="${NOT #authorization.expression('hasRole(''ROLE_USER'')')}"
           th:href="@{/login}"  class="btn btn-primary"> Login </a>
        <a th:if="${#authorization.expression('hasRole(''ROLE_USER'')')}"
           th:href="@{/logout}" class="btn btn-primary"> Logout </a>
        ...
<body>
```

In if it doesn't work try replacing`ROLE_USER` by `USER`